# integrate watir-webdriver and browsermob/proxy and webdriver-user-agent

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I love watir webdriver and want to use it :)

Also love webdriver-user-agent

and browsermob-proxy

the thing is just started with ruby and Im confused about running those three together hier is the code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'webdriver-user-agent'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("/home/ubuntu/ruby/browsermob-proxy")
server.start

proxy = server.create_proxy

browser = Watir::Browser.new Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(:browser => :chrome, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => :landscape)
browser.goto 'google.com'
```

so how can I integrate proxy to the browser?

Comment: Hey, when you say integrate what do you mean?  If i take your question to mean how do you connect to a proxy it would just be a port and then localhost.

Answer (score 1):

if the server port is 8080 then you would do something like this

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new :http => 'localhost:8080:, :ssl => 'localhost:8080'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```

Comment: b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile with chrome doesn't work. if I do b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome chrome starts

Comment: with :firefox it works, but with webdriver-user-agent it doesn't. browser = Watir::Browser.new Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(:browser => :firefox, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => :landscape). .har file is almost empty

Answer (score 1):

Something on these lines should work:

```
driver = Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(:browser => :chrome, :agent => :iphone, :orientation => :landscape)
browser = Watir::Browser.new driver, :switches => %w[--proxy-server=#{proxy.host}:#{proxy.port}]
browser.goto 'google.com'
```

Since you have already created the proxy, it's host and port values will be available (browsermob might not create the proxy on default port 8080, so I would advice to pick it from the proxy object itself).